# Can I invoke a django view using management command?

Tags: python, django, django-commands

I have a view that I want to call using a management command, is this even possible ? I read through the django help, but I was not super clear on this aspect.

I am currently running it on a  development REST server.My views just send out an email, so REST might not be necessarily required. I want to run this periodically. I was thinking management command is the best way to do this, since it will eliminate the need to run the development test server ?

Comment: Why not just isolate the code that sends email, then call it from your management command as well as your view?

Comment: I second that. The purpose of a View is to handle an HTTP request. Move your code that sends the email to a function so you can call it in your management command.